# Vector form of $vdv=adx$

Tags: kinematics, vectors, calculus

I have studied that $vdv=adx$ in motion in 1D, it is derived as

$$a= \frac{dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = v \frac{dv}{dx}$$

I want to know if its vector form, $v \cdot dv= a \cdot dx$, is proper and how we would prove it.

Comment: See this answer: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/731008/226902

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see its vector form, you can repeat the previous derivation, but in 2D:

$$\vec{a} = \frac{d \vec{v}}{dt} = \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x_1} \frac{dx_1}{dt} + \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x_2} \frac{dx_2}{dt} = v_1 \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x_1} + v_2 \frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial x_2} = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{\nabla} \vec{v}$$

Be aware that the dot product happens between $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{\nabla}$. You need to know something about differential calculus. The same reasoning is valid also in 3D or any number of space dimensions.

**Edit:** The comments below refer to a previous version of the answer. Also, it is worth checking [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/456623/226902) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/552610/226902) related posts.

Comment: I think that the original question does not refer to vector fields, just vector functions of only time (i.e. point particles).

Comment: @Quillo the derivation is the same. And he is refering to functions of x and t, you can see it in his formula.

Comment: @geofiuse  there is no partial derivative in time. The question is clearly about a single trajectory. Given the basic level of the question is much better not to create confusion by introducing fields. Anyway, this question is a clear duplicate, e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/552602/226902

Comment: @Quillo You are the one talking about fields. I just have a function f(x1(t),x2(t),t). It could be anything

Comment: @Quillo if there is no t dependency, that partial is zero. It's general case.

Comment: In that case there is NO partial derivative in time! Since you keep it, it means that you are talking about fields, even if you do not write "field" explicitly. See: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/552610/226902

Comment: @Quillo what if I have a particle moving with v = (x2*t, x1*t^2 +1)? Honest question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147486/discussion-between-geofisue-and-quillo).